# Select * from table where colum = username not working

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to implement discount code on a site where the payment gateway is stipe, everything kinda working fine but when i try to get the % of the discount base on the promo code the user input from the database its not working, instead of charging the discounted price, it charge the full price and completely ignores the discount

here the code

```
$getcode = $getcode[1];
$user = $_SESSION['username'];
$total = $_SESSION['totprice'];

$sql6 = 'SELECT * from promocode where username="'.$user.'" and promo_code="'.$getcode.'" ';
$result6 = mysqli_query($con, $sql6);

while($row6 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result6)) {
    echo "Discount: " . $row6["discount"]. "<br>";

    $discount =$row6["discount"];
    $grandtotal= $total - (($discount * $total) / 100);

    $publishable_key    = "*******************";
    $secret_key         = "********************";

    if(isset($_POST['stripeToken'])){


    Stripe::setApiKey($secret_key);
    $description    = "Invoice #".rand(99999,999999999) ;
    $amount     = $grandtotal;
    $user   = $_SESSION['username'];
```

so instead of

```
$amount = $total - (($discount * $total) / 100);
```

its giving me

```
$amount = $total;
```

for some reason

Comment: What is in `$amount` and what is in `$discount`?

Comment: @user3783243 I tried to clean up the formatting, I might not have gotten it exactly right. He had the `<br>` in a non-code block.

Comment: Each time through the loop you're subtracting the current row's discount from `$total`, and putting that in `$grandtotal`. But you never reduce `$total`, so the final result is just the discount from the last row.

Answer (score 1):

You're not accumulating all the discounts. Each time through the loop you just apply the current row's discount to the total, overwriting what you calculated from the previous rows.

Initialize `$grandtotal` to the total, then subtract from it each time through.

Also, you shouldn't allow lots of discounts to let the grand total go below 0. I check for that at the end.

```
$grandtotal = $total;
while ($row6 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result6)) {
    echo "Discount: " . $row6["discount"]. "<br>";
    $discount = $row6["discount"];
    $grandtotal -= $total - (($discount * $total) / 100);
}
if ($grandtotal < 0) {
    $grandtotal = 0;
}
```